# Power BI - Divide sum of column values by number of columns

Tags: powerbi

Experts,

I have a scenario where my table visualization has data like this:

```
Org    |Jan     |Feb     |Mar
Foo    |200     |100     |100
Bar    |150     |250     |200
```

There are some other columns too, all this data is not coming from 1 single dataset.

What I am looking for is a way to sum the values in the month columns and divide them by the number of columns. In this case, my expected output is:

```
Org    |Jan     |Feb     |Mar        |Output
Foo    |200     |100     |100        |133.33 (i.e. 200+100+100 / 3)
Bar    |150     |250     |200        |200 (i.e. 150+250+200 / 3)
```

I can create measure and can get this to work with static values, BUT, if the number of months keep adding - let's say tomorrow I get the data for April and May as well, I would want to sum the values for the 5 months and divide them by 5. How can I accomplish this?

It's something like - Do a SUM of all columns (i.e. all months available) EXCEPT "Org" column and then DIVIDE by the number of months available (obviously we need to exclude "Org" column)

Comment: I think you can use Measure with Average and Metrics visual for your presentation. Can you show some sample raw data?

Comment: Columns are not dynamic in business intelligence models. They should not be treated like rows of data. You should think about remodeling your data.

Comment: You should Pivot your data, and move it to rows rather than columns